# Do we have any spark libraries to connect from databricks to opensearch

Tags: elasticsearch, pyspark, databricks, opensearch, aws-databricks

`While using elastic search library "org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12:7.13.3" which is working fine if target is elastic search 7.10 but with opensearch 2.3  as target it is giving issue like mapping parser exception. Basically while building bulk api request it is missing index name as part of request as given below.

```
{"index":{"_id":50}} <-- name missing in BULK API syntax
{"name":"Bilbo","age":50}
{"index":{"_id":1000}}
{"name":"Gandalf","age":1000}
{"index":{"_id":195}}
{"name":"Thorin","age":195}
{"index":{"_id":178}}
{"name":"Balin","age":178}
{"index":{"_id":77}}
{"name":"Kili","age":77}
```

Below is code used

```
df.write
  .format( "org.elasticsearch.spark.sql" )
  .option( "es.nodes",   host )
  .option( "es.nodes",   nodes )
  .option( "es.port",    443     )
  .option( "es.net.ssl", "true"      )
  .option("es.resource",index/type)
  .option( "es.nodes.wan.only", "true" )
  .option( "es.net.http.auth.user",username)
  .option( "es.net.http.auth.pass",password)
  .mode( "append" )
  .save()
```

same code is writing data if target host is an elastic search host but failing with opensearch host `

Answer (score 0):

There is an opensearch-spark library that you can build. They are going to release a maven central version soon.

https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-build/issues/3385